# PHPExcel: How to Set an a Sheet's Paper Size with a User-Defined Paper Size?

Tags: php, phpexcel

By using

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
   ->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);` 
we can set a sheet's page size, but how do you supply a custom Paper Size for this? I want to set it to **8.5' x 13.0'**, Letter is **8.5 x 11.0** while Legal is **8.5 x 14.0**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the source code for the library you're using at
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet/PageSetup.php#L35-L100

Line of interest is this one in the comments.

```
* 14 = Folio paper (8.5 in. by 13 in.)
```

Which you can use:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->
getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_FOLIO);
```

It doesn't seem like you can set custom sizes though, only the predefined ones.